# What is puncturing?

Tags: limits

My math book keeps referring to "puncturing" in the context of limits. I have not been able to find any definition or explanation for this term. What does it mean?

Comment: Maybe it is finding the limit, which graphically means that you can "fill" the hole in the graph and thus create a piece wise function that then becomes continuous. I do find the terminology a bit odd.

Comment: It seems an object becomes "punctured" by removing one point. But you might get a better explanation if you edit the question to show one or two quotations from mathematical texts where "puncturing" was mentioned.

Comment: You want $0 <$, not $\le$.  Not just complex analysis.  See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)#Deleted_neighbourhood)

Comment: Punctured usually references "punctured (or deleted) neighborhood" in complex analysis where $$0<z-z_0|<p$$ Where you could probably modify this to include a epsilon delta proof with respect to limits

Comment: Yeah that last was a typo lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of limits I have seen the punctured neighbourhood of a point $a$ defined as a union of open intervals each
of width $r$, but excluding $a$ itself ( hence punctured )

$$
N_r(a)=\,]a-r,a[ \,\cup \, ]a,a+r[
$$

I expect there are some variations on this theme.

Comment: Another term in the same context for "punctured" is "deleted". +1